# Graph of real continuous function has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f\colon[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Show that its graph has measure zero.

I've tried with the following idea but I got stuck:

Let $\epsilon >0$, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $ |x-y|< \delta \implies  |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Let $P=\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$ be a partition of the interval $[a,b]$ with $ |x_i-x_{i-1}|<\delta$.

The graph of $f$ is $G(f)=\{(x,f(x)) : x \in [a,b]\}$, and $G(f) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n [x_{i-1},x_i]\times[m_i,M_i]$, where $m_i=\min_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$,$M_i=\max_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$.

We have $ |G(f)|_e \leq \sum_{i=1}^nm([x_{i-1},x_i].m([m_i,M_i])<n\delta\epsilon$. At this point I got stuck, I need to arrive to an inequality with $\epsilon$ times a constant or something of the sort. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: $m([x_{i-1},x_i]$ means volume of $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, right?

Comment: @pozcukushimatostreet yes it’s the length of the interval.

Comment: $|G(f) |_e$ means measure of $G(f)$, right?

Comment: and how did you get ''  $G(f) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n [x_{i-1},x_i]\times[m_i,M_i]$, where $m_i=\min_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$,$M_i=\max_{x \in [x_{i-1},x_i]} f(x)$ ''?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: your $n\delta$ can be replaced by $b-a$.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Is my solution ok with that correction?

Comment: @user156441  Yes. The uniform continuity is the main observation.

Comment: Since $x_i - x_{i-1} < \delta$ for all $i$, shouldn't $b - a$ be less than $n\delta$?

Comment: @kobe $x_i$'s form a partition. Only intervals of this partition are short.

Comment: How do you know that $(b - a)/\delta$ is an integer?

Comment: @kobe Oh, I understand your point, I hope. But after the suggested correction we have not $n\delta$, but simply $|G(f)|_\epsilon<(b-a)\epsilon$.

Comment: Right, I had just posted that.  :-)

Comment: question, I have been stuck on this for a while, so how do you get bounded by the $\epsilon (b-a)$? because the sigma of measures I thought was measure in the domain and not codomain so how do you get the $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 10):

This isn't really relevant to this specific problem, but I just want to add that this result is still true for any Borel-measurable function. This is realized as a trivial consequence of Fubini's Theorem.

Let $m_1$ and $m_2$ denote 1- and 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure, respectively, and let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Then $$ m_2(G_f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} 1_{G_f} dm_2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{G_f}(x,y) dy dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} m_1(\{ f(x) \}) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} 0 dx = 0$$

Comment: This is true, but one first needs to prove that $G_f$ is $m_2$-measurable.

Comment: $G_f$ is always measurable (when $f$ is measurable), because $G_f=h^{-1}(\{0\})$, where $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is the measurable mapping defined by $h(x,y)=y-f(x)$.

Comment: And $h$ is the difference of two measurable functions $(x,y) \to y$ and $(x,y) \to f(x)$, and so it's measurable.

Answer (score 6):

Since $m([m_i,M_i]) < \varepsilon$ for all $i \in \{0,1,\ldots, n\}$,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n m([x_{i-1},x_i])m([m_i,M_i]) < \sum_{i = 1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})\varepsilon = (b - a)\varepsilon.$$