# Showing that the unit circle has measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, circles

How can  I show that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: |x| =1\}$ has measure zero using the definition of measure zero? I don't want to use the interpretation of measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as area (and then show this by using the fact that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$. I was thinking somehow find rectangles to that contain the circumference of this circle and keeping one of the sides of each rectangle free to make $\varepsilon$-small. I'm not able to get ahead with this approach though. Thoughts and ideas?

Note - this question is NOT a duplicate of [Graph of real continuous function has measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209749/graph-of-real-continuous-function-has-measure-zero) because it focuses on a specific example. The results from the other question might be modifiable to apply here, but look at something different.

Comment: OK to use compactness in proof?

Comment: Yes, I tried using compactness, but I'm running into the problem that the finite cover of $n$ (say) rectangles I get in the end depends on my choice of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Here is an idea you can elaborate: Consider n evenly spaced points on the unit circle, then at each points you draw a rectangle/square center at those points with side length large enough to cover the circle. Then the amount of rectangles you draw will be $\mathcal{O}(n)$, but the area of each circle will be $\mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$, let $n$ goes to infinity......

Comment: Your title says "unit circle" but your text says "|x|= 1".  Do you understand that "|x|= 1" is **not** a circle?  (It is a square with its diagonals along the coordinate axes.)

Comment: @user247327 OP might be using $|x|$ as a notation for the Euclidean norm of $x$.

Comment: Yes, I'm using $|x|$ to denote $||x||_{2}$. I thought this is the conventional notation, but I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is a duplicate of the other thread, because you can simply divide the circle into two genuine functions, and since the union of two sets of measure zero still has measure zero, you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the regular $4n$-gon with $(1,0)$ being a vertex.  We can cover the circle by $4n$ rectangles
$$
\overline{\operatorname{conv}}\left\{\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right),\cos\left(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)\right\}\times
\overline{\operatorname{conv}}\left\{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right),\sin\left(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)\right\},\quad k=0,1,\dots,4n-1
$$
The sum of measures of these rectangles is
\begin{align*}
&\sum_k\left\lvert\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)\right\rvert\cdot\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{(k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)\right\rvert\\
&=4\sum_k\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{4n}\right)\right\rvert\cdot\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{4n}\right)\right\rvert\\
&=2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\sum_k\left\lvert\sin\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}\right)\right\rvert\\
&\leq 2\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4n}\right)\cdot 4n\to 0\quad\text{as }n\to\infty.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

I will show that
the difference between
the areas of the
circumscribed and inscribed
$n$-gons goes to zero.

Consider a regular $n$-gon
inscribed in the unit circle.

There are $2n$ triangles
with central angle
$t = \pi/n$
and hypotenuse
$1$,
so the distance to the side
$s_n$ and length $h_n$
satisfy
$s_n = \cos(t)$
and $h_n = \sin(t)$.
The area of each triangle
is thus
$\frac12 s_nh_n
=\frac12\cos(t)\sin(t)
=\frac14\sin(2t)
$
so the area of the
inscribed $n$-gon is
$2n$ times this or
$\frac12n\sin(2t)
$.

Extend the radii
to get the
circumscribed $n$-gon.
There are $2n$ triangles
with base $1$
and height
$g_n$ such that
$g_n = \tan(t)$,
so the area is
$\frac12 g_n
=\frac12 \tan(t)
$.

The total area is thus
$n\tan(t)
$.

Note that
both of these areas go to
$\pi$ as $n \to \infty$
since
$\sin(x) \approx \tan(x)
\approx x$
as $x \to 0$.
However,
the only inequality needed is
$\sin(x) < x$
for $0 < x < \pi/2$.

The difference in
the two areas is thus

$\begin{array}\\
D_n
&=n\tan(t)-\frac12 n\sin(2t)\\
&=n\left(\tan(t)-\frac12 \sin(2t)\right)\\
&=n\left(\dfrac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}-\sin(t)\cos(t)\right)\\
&=n\sin(t)\left(\dfrac{1}{\cos(t)}-\cos(t)\right)\\
&=n\sin(t)\dfrac{1-\cos^2(t)}{\cos(t)}\\
&=n\sin(t)\dfrac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos(t)}\\
&=n\dfrac{\sin^3(t)}{\cos(t)}\\
&=n\dfrac{\sin^3(t)}{1-2\sin^2(t/2)}\\
\end{array}
$

We now use
$\sin(x) < x$
for
$0 < x < \pi/2$
so

$\begin{array}\\
D_n
&\lt n\dfrac{t^3}{1-2(t/2)^2}\\
&= n\dfrac{(\pi/n)^3}{1-2(\pi/(2n))^2}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{n^2}\dfrac{\pi^3}{1-\pi^2/(2n^2)}\\
&< \dfrac{2\pi^3}{n^2}
\qquad\text{for } n \ge 4\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Nice! can you please help in how the extended radii is $\tan(t)$?

Comment: The radius is 1 and the height $g$ (small side) of the circumscribed triangle with central angle $t$ satisfies height/radius = tan(t).