# Show that $T:=\{(\cos(t),\sin(t)):t\in[0,2\pi)\}$ is Lebesgue measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Show that $$T:=\{(\cos(t),\sin(t)):t\in[0,2\pi)\}$$ is Lebesgue measure zero.

---

I've got this problem and I know that i can solve this by showing the measure of 2 circle of radius $1
+\epsilon,1-\epsilon$ but I don't know how to prove this by taking a bounding countable sets and bounded countable sets.
I had an idea of taking the interval $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and divide it by $4n^2$ equal squares with $1/n$ segment. and then Showing the amount of squares which covers the sphere will be some constant times $n$.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is your definition of measure set?

Comment: You should say "Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^2$ "

Comment: Yes, that's my question.

Comment: You could use the fact that the area of a half unit disk is $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \ dx$? No? And then apply your initial idea.

Comment: There are specific answers with covering with n-gons here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3240769/399263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We know that:

*If $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous function, so its graph has measure zero.*

If you have problem with prove that, you can say me and I will write the prove about that fact.

And, now you can divide the circle into two genuine functions, and *since the union of two sets of Lebesgue measure zero still has Lebesgue measure zero*, so you can prove what $T$ is Lebesgue measure zero.