# Prove that the graph of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> **Lemma**. The graph of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has measure zero.

*Note: this question has been answered before in various forms, but I want to see if my proof (i.e. the one most intuitive to me) is correct.*

We will use a countable covering $S = \cup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} S_q $ of G and show that each $S_q$ has measure zero.

Define $G := \{ (x, f(x)) : x \in \mathbb{R} \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, which is the graph of $f$.

Assume $\delta \le 1$ and $\epsilon < 0$.

$$
S_q := \{(q-\delta, q+\delta) \times (f(q) - \epsilon, f(q)+\epsilon) : q \in \mathbb{Q} \} \tag{1}
$$

Given the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
$x \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \exists q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$x \in (q - \delta, q + \delta) \tag{2} $$

Now we have $|x - q| < \delta$ and, from the continuity of $f$, $|f(x) - f(q)| < \epsilon$. It immediately follows that
$$
f(x) \in (f(q) - \epsilon, f(q)+\epsilon) \tag{3}
$$

Since $x \in \mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary, we now know that $S$ is a covering from $(2)$ and $(3)$. Showing that each $S_q$ in $(1)$ has measure zero will complete the proof, since the countable union of zero sets has measure zero. For any $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, write

$$
|S_q| = 2\delta 2\epsilon \le 2\epsilon.
\square
$$

Comment: Really you have not shown the sets have measure zero. Indeed, they do not have measure zero, but rather a measure less than some $\epsilon$. However, in consideration of the countable union thereof, the measure of $S$ would appear to be, if the $S_q$ are disjoint, potentially some $\infty\cdot\epsilon$ situation... for this approach, you need to be more careful and use the $\epsilon\cdot2^{-n}$ technique (or something similar), whereby the union acts as a geometric series and then $S$ has measure less than $\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$. *Then* you are done!

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209749/graph-of-real-continuous-function-has-measure-zero)

Comment: IsaacR24, It is worth mentioning that although I have seen what I discussed in my comment used many times with success, if one is not careful things do go wrong. I deleted an answer due to such a mistake, with thanks to @ArcticChar for spotting it.

Comment: FShrike: can you elaborate on $S_k$ have a measure of only "some" $\epsilon$? See my response to Arctic Char's answer as well.

Comment: You have erroneously assumed that $f$ is uniformly continuous. There might not exist $\delta>0$ such that $\forall q\in \Bbb Q \,\forall x\in (q-\delta, q+\delta)\,(|f(x)-f(q)|<\epsilon\,)$ even in a simple case such as $f(x)=x^2.$ You can fix this by showing $G_n=^{def}\{(x,f(x)):x\in [n,n+1]\}$ is Lebesgue-null for each $n\in \Bbb Z$ so that $G=\cup_{n\in\Bbb Z}G_n$ is also null, using the uniform continuity of $f$ on each $[n,n+1].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of continuity reads as follow:

> $f$ is continuous at $x$, if for any $\epsilon >0$, there is $\delta >0$ so that $y\in (x-\delta , x+\delta)$ implies $f(y) \in (f(x)-\epsilon, f(x)+ \epsilon)$.

Note that $\delta$ depends on both $\epsilon$ and $x$. So you don't get to choose the width $\delta$ of your $S_q$. It depends on both $\epsilon$ and $q\in \mathbb Q$. In particular, for any $x\in \mathbb R$, it is not clear if $x \in (q-\delta , q+\delta)$ for some $q\in \mathbb Q$: the density of $\mathbb Q$ is not sufficient.

To deal with that, please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209749/graph-of-real-continuous-function-has-measure-zero). Instead of $\mathbb R$, one consider continuous function
$$ f: [-M, M] \to\mathbb R$$
to show that this graph has measure zero. The main tools is that now $f$ is uniform continuous, thus $\delta$ is chosen independent of $x$ (Please read the details in that post).

With that result, the graph of $f : \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a countable union of that of $f|_{[-M, M]}$, where $M \in \mathbb N$. Thus it is also of measure zero.

(Another mistake in your post is the claim that $S_q$ is of measure zero. This is of course not true).

Comment: I now see clearly that I've failed to partition R, since I can't control the width of $\delta$. But for each $S_q$, given the continuity of $f$, I thought $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $|S_q| < \epsilon$ . Where did I go wrong here? Note that I have a "gold standard" proof to this problem, see solution 4 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~brent/files/105_hw5.pdf). It just wasn't fully intuitive to me (but is becoming more so).

Comment: It is true that for all $\epsilon >0$, $|S_q|<C\epsilon$ for some constant $C$. But $S_q$ is not a fixed set, it also depends on $\epsilon$ (and also $\delta$). @IsaacR24

Comment: I'm misunderstanding something important about the definition of measure zero then...doesn't this suggest $S_q$ is of measure zero, since $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small? @Arctic Char

Comment: Yes, if you have a fixed set $A$ and $|A| \le \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$, then $A$ is a measure zero set. But if $A$ depends on $\epsilon$, that it's not fixed. (It's not really related to measure theory: we have $0 < \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$, it does not imply that $\epsilon/2$ is zero. @IsaacR24

Comment: And now I see why compactness/uniform continuity is the missing insight here, so I can avoid the dependence on $\epsilon$ and x. Thanks so much for multiple elaborations, @Arctic Char!