# Content or measure zero of a graph of a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm starting to learn some basic definitions that are presented on Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, mainly Measure ant content zero. The definition for measure zero is that, for every $\varepsilon >0$, we have a set of closed rectangles such that $E \subset\bigcup_{k \in \Bbb{N}} R_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu (R_k) < \varepsilon$. Content zero is the same but with finitely many rectangles.

Now, my question is, does the graph of a continuous function has content zero? I'm aware that the [graph of real continuous function has measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209749/graph-of-real-continuous-function-has-measure-zero). I completely understand the OP solution with the correction gave there. But the solution implies that it has content zero as well? Indeed, in a part of the proof, we get that $$G(f) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n [x_{i-1},x_i]\times[m_i,M_i],$$ i.e., we can cover $G(f)$ by a finite amount of closed rectangles, mainly, $\{[x_{i-1},x_i]\times[m_i,M_i]:1\le i\le n\}$. Which, by definition, it implies that it has content zero as well. Am I correct or am I making a dumb mistake?

Comment: Because the graph is compact (closed and bounded), yes, the content is zero. For unbounded graphs, obviously infinitely many rectangles are needed to cover it. But the simple definition you have for content zero was not intended for unbounded sets in the first place. When one wants to discuss content (instead of measure) for unbounded sets, the concept needs to be extended, very much in the same vein as proper vs improper Riemann integrals.